# How to get an string to an int then send it to a different method

Tags: java, string, methods, int

I am trying to get my string that comes in off my driver to become an int than be sent to the convertToBinary() that way it can be used to figure out the binary. Any help would be great!

```
   class DecimalBinary   {

      private String decimal = "0";
      private String binary = "";

      public void setDecimal(String decimal){
         int intdecimal = Integer.parseInt(decimal);
         convertToBinary();
      }

      public String convertToBinary(){
         int pow = 128;
         intdecimal = 0;


         while (intdecimal > 0){

            if (intdecimal >= pow){
              binary += "1";
              intdecimal = intdecimal - pow;
            } 
            else if (intdecimal < pow){
                binary += "0";
            }
         pow = pow / 2;

         }

      return binary;
      }

      public String  toString(){
          return decreturn + " is " + binary + " in binary";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a build in way to convert to binary strings! Your method can be reduced to

```
private String binary;

public void setDecimal(String decimal){
   int intdecimal = Integer.parseInt(decimal);
   binary = Integer.toBinaryString(intdecimal);
}
```

But, if you want to stick with your own binary conversion method, then, as the first answer says, you need to pass a parameter.

The problem is that your `intdecimal` variable in the `setDecimal` method is not the same as the `intdecimal` in your conversion method!

Answer (score 0):

Your convert method first needs a parameter:

```
public String convertToBinary(int decimal){
     int pow = 128;

     while (decimal > 0){

        if (decimal >= pow){
          binary += "1";
          decimal = decimal - pow;
        } 
        else if (decimal < pow){
            binary += "0";
        }
     pow = pow / 2;

     }

  return binary;
  }
```

and then be called like this:

```
  public void setDecimal(String decimal){
     int intdecimal = Integer.parseInt(decimal);
     convertToBinary(intdecimal);
  }
```

Comment: So that works. How would i go about getting my toString method to work to allow me to send it out to the driver?

Comment: You can call it like this: System.out.println(decimal.toString()). I would advice you to add a main method for the calls.

Answer (score 0):

when are you calling the `convertToBinary` function pass decimal `convertToBinary(decimal)`;

```java
public String convertToBinary(int dec)
{ 
    decimal=dec;
}
```